# What is Causing Scrolling of Page, When not needed

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following code, something is calculating too much height, that I can't see the footer and this causes scrolling when there should be no scrolling.

*note: I am using reactjs, sass so this is why I may have some extra wrappers and maybe some of the css is duplicated as I had to take it out of the nesting.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

ul.sidebar-menu {
  padding: 0;
  li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    color: blue;
  }
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

header {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}

main {
  flex: 2 auto;
  display: block;
}

footer {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
  
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                header
            </header>
            <nav>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>  
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
               main 
            </main>
            <footer>footer</footer>
          </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also for my ul.sidebar-menu how would I add scrolling to this area. I guess I have to set a height for it?

Comment: What is your minimum browser requirement? That will affect solutions. For example you could use flexbox, or grid or older CSS.

Comment: IE 11 is the lowest browser I will support, so can't use grid, so using flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tryed something here that should do the job with the scrollbar when too much content https://jsfiddle.net/fnvgho41/11/

Needed to wrap you nav & main with a section to manage easily the height.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}

ul.sidebar-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
    color: blue;
  }
}

.body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

nav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}

main {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
  
        <div class="wrapper">
            <header>
                header
            </header>
            <div class="body">
            <nav>
                <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>
                <li>
                    Home
                </li>  
              </ul>
            </nav>
            <main>
               main 
            </main>
            </div>
            <footer>footer</footer>
          </div>
    
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: from your example it seems to be what I asked for, seems like I was mostly just missing one more wrapper to get it correct. Why did you use section instead of something like aside? Also if I would need to make the sidebar scroll able or even the headers or footer sticky. Would that require alot of modifications?

Comment: I did remove the section, it has no semantic. I just forgot remove a `height: 100%;`. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height: 100%;` from your `nav` element

```
nav {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  flex: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: If I remove that, then the header and footer become huge.

Comment: What are the requirement? Can you have a fixed header/footer height?

Comment: I think it can be fixed or at least a min height. I don't know how big the logo is and that would be the size the header will be. Footer might be pretty tiny with like copyright on it.